# Problem in python program where we get a string from a given one and replace all occurrences of its first character with '$' sign

Tags: python

This is the full question:
**Write a Python program to get a string from a given string where all occurrences of its first char have been changed to '$', except the first char itself.
Sample String : 'restart'
Expected Result : 'resta$t'**

The code I gave was as follows:

```
e="Test string"
f=""
for k in range(0,len(e)):  
    if(str[k]==e[0]):
        f+="$"
    else:
        f+=e[k]
print("New string: ",f)
```

The error I got back was in this line:
if(str[k]==e[0]):
The error shown was TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
***I made an observation that if I replaced the variable e with str, I get the result without issues. Does this mean I can only run this code using str as a variable, or is there an alternate solution?***

Comment: You need round brackets, `str(k)`, to cast to a `str`. However, it will simply convert a number to a string type.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I made that error.

Comment: What is the motivation for using `str` at all? Why should `str[k]` be the kth character of string `e`?

Comment: if 't' is the first letter in the word should it replace 'T' with '$' or not?

Comment: It should replace every occurrence of T in the string, including the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

This works like you want, I think:

```py
e = "test String"
f = e[0]
for char in e[1:]:
    if char == e[0]:
        f+="$"
    else:
        f+=char

print(f)

#  tes$ S$ring
```

Though I have a suspicion there must be some more pythonic way

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented your question in a easy way.

```
e="restart"
x=e[0]
e1=e.replace(x,'$')
e2=x+e1[1::]
print(e2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
quote="If you cannot make it good, at least make it look good."
quoteList = list(quote)
for i in range(len(quoteList)):
  quoteList[0] = "$"
  if quoteList[i] == " ":
    quoteList[i+1] = "$"
"".join(quoteList)
```

Comment: This code is not correct. It replaces every character in the string after a single whitespace with the `$` symbol. Additional text could have also been helpful in why you think this adds any value in comparison to the other answers